# How to approach manager to give in-lieu leave?

Tags: leave

I am working from home this weekend to catch up with work for deadline next week Tuesday.

How to approach my manager to give me in-lieu leave?

As I am a developer, I have history commits on my Git. Is it enough to ask him  based on Git commits?

Comment: Usually your contract has rules for how to handle over time and working at off office hours (and days). You should first look at that if there is something that supports your request. On the other hand you should have approached your manager  on Thursday latest. You should have known then already that you will not meet the deadline without working extra hours on weekend.

Comment: Your commits are not a reliable way of time tracking. Before approaching the topic at all, you'll need to write down your work times and breaks.

Comment: Has your overtime been sanctioned?

Answer (score 4):

Just ask.

Hey, boss - can I get some time off since I'm working the weekend?

You'll get either a "Yes", "No", or "I'll think about it" in response.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach my boss with: I done X extra hours to meet the deadline because "insert important reasons related to the project". Can we put those hours in a time bank or a side note if there is no time bank in the company? Then I would make a second request to use the time bank.

Then next time, I would get the green light of my boss before doing any overtime because I personally find it rude doing overtime with the intent to request time off before asking. In my eyes, it is the same as a worker fixing something at my house where he hand me a bill that is over the estimate and he never consult me before busting the estimate.

Your work time is owned by your boss where he is accounted for it by his boss. Doing more time on a task and then be unavailable for another can jeopardize his plan.

Good luck!